# Upstart - when a given event occurs, in what order are the jobs run?

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.3, and am using upstart as the init daemon (pretty sure this is the default).

When a given event occurs, in what order are the jobs run? Specifically, I'm referring to jobs defined in /etc/init, not to any system V init scripts bridged over via rc-sysinit.conf.

As a specific example, suppose I have the following jobs defined in /etc/init to start on startup:

- hostname.conf
- module-init-tools.conf
- mountall.conf
- udev-finish.conf
- udevmonitor.conf
- udevtrigger.conf

in what order will these be run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unspecified order. Refer to [the upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#order-in-which-jobs-which-start-on-the-same-event-are-run)

Answer (score 1):

It's defined inside the /etc/init/*.conf files, the parameter startup on indicates which services must be already up, or which runlevel must be running.
With that, you can make an useful diagram of what your system exactly does.
I did it that way to workaround some weird udevtrigger hang up, until I know the best stop parameter to give to it.